# How do I get a default date to be specific date from props passed object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

Hi trying to fill my form with data from a database via initial values in formik . I am using Input type =date from reactstrap. when the form load I want all fields including date field to show current object date value

then the user can choose a new date if they want else the date stays on unchanged and is submitted to db with other form data if that is the case.

```
                <div className="col-xl-10">
                  <Input
                    id="dob"
                    type="date"
                    value={values.dob}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className="form-control"/>
                </div>
```

Comment: i've tried , default and placeholder, the data is passed into formik with  this.state.value, it seems the Input field cant be overwritten and is stuck MM/dd/yyyy  any help would be tremendous

Answer (score 0):

I set the input value initially and the date can show

```
state = {
    values: {
        dob: '2012-12-12'
    }
}

handleChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
        values: {
            ...this.state.values,
            [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
        }
    });
    //console.log(evt.target.value)
}

render() { 
    const { values } = this.state;

    return (
          <div className="col-xl-10">
              <Input name='dob'
                id="dob"
                type="date"
                value={values.dob}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                className="form-control"/>
          </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Ok Yimei  thank you I will give that a try and update

Comment: Yimei ,  by the way I punted this problem. I will re tackle ,  just decided to use a  library